# THREAD_OS_ID in in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

MySQL 5.7 introduced the column `THREAD_OS_ID` in the table `performance_schema.threads`. Is it possible to get the thread id in MySQL 5.6?